# Переопределить виджет "Свежие записи"

Tags: wordpress

Можно ли каким-нибудь образом переопределить шаблон виджета "Свежие записи"?
Например в Joomla как известно можно переопределить шаблоны модулей, компонентов. Мне нужно в виджете свежие записи выводить кроме заголовка, картинку, дату создания и категорию

Comment: Короткий ответ - можно все, в том числе и полностью переписать виджет. Но для начала надо понимать, о каком виджете идет речь - стандартный WP, или из скачанной темы, из плагина?

Comment: Стандартный виджет. Мне бы хотелось чтобы в виджете выводились записи в таком виде: Картинка, Заголовок, Дата создания, Просмотры (стоит плагин WP-PostViews), Текст записи (кусочек).

Comment: Стандартный реализован классом `WP_Widget_Recent_Posts`, от которого можно сделать наследование и переписать функцию widget(). Ну или сделать свой шорткод и выводить записи им через текстовый виджет. Второй способ более прост для понимания. Какой вариант привести в ответе?

Comment: ответил вторым вариантом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код с одного из моих сайтов:

```
/**
 * Shortcode to output recent posts.
 *
 * @param array $atts Shortcode attributes.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function recent_posts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category'            => '',
        'number'              => -1,
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'orderby'             => 'date',
        'tag'                 => '',
        'exclude_posts'       => '',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    ), $atts );

    $args = array(
        'category_name'       => $atts['category'],
        'showposts'           => $atts['number'],
        'order'               => strtoupper( $atts['order'] ),
        'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
        'tag'                 => explode( ',', $atts['tag'] ),
        'post__not_in'        => explode( ',', $atts['exclude_posts'] ),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => $atts['ignore_sticky_posts'],
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $return_string = '<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $return_string .= '<li>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-date">' . get_the_date( 'j F Y' ) . '</div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-thumbnail">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'full' ) . '</div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-more"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Читать полностью</a></div>';
            $return_string .= '</li>';
        }
        $return_string .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        $return_string = 'Нет записей';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode( 'recent_posts', 'recent_posts_shortcode' );
```

Код надо поместить в functions.php вашей темы.

Для использования создайте текстовый виджет, в нем напишите такой текст:

```
[recent_posts number="5"]
```

Шорткод принимает несколько параметров: категория записей (category, по умолчанию - все), кол-во постов (number, по умолчанию - все), сортировка (order, по умолчанию - вниз), сортировка по (orderby, по умолчанию - по дате), теги списком (tag, по умолчанию - любые), не выводить посты (exclude_posts), игнорировать прилепленные посты (ignore_sticky_posts, по умолчанию - да).

Шорткод можно вставлять в любое место сайта, как текст.

Из этого кода легко сделать собственный плагин, который может пригодиться на нескольких сайтах.

Comment: Спасибо.. Сейчас попробую его

Comment: А функцию recent_posts_shortcode() как вызвать в шаблоне? Или через админку нужно?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, насчет использования

Comment: Аа понял. Спасибо.. Давно не делал сайты на WP поэтому все забыл. В основном на Joomla делаю) Еще раз спасибо. Только небольшой вопрос. Как ограничить число записей например выводить только 5 записей последних?

Comment: уже дополнил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Ты б дописал. что плагин из него сделать будет лучше, чем в файл функций. Всё-таки это не функции темы, а "глобальная" задача.

Comment: @SeVlad ты, конечно, прав по поводу глобальности, но людям, которые мало работали с WP, слова "свой плагин " навевают тоску)
Допишу.

Comment: Так надо дать ссылку на [ман](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) И образование и пугаться не будут. Что там такого сложного - всего-то и нужно, что заголовки прописать :)